# Bug when showing the newest question of a particular tag

Tags: bug

After the new [filtering feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement?cb=1) I have noticed that sometimes when clicking on some particular **tag** (read, it can be any tag) of the **Watched Tags** section those questions are not the newest i.e the page shows older questions (from about `1` hour ago).

To add more detail, the `URL` that I see on the browser in these cases is something like:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/<tag_name_here>
```

However, and eventually, if I keep clicking on the **tag** or refreshing the page, the newest questions appear. Is someone else experiencing the same behavior?

Comment: I've been seeing the same thing over on superuser for a few hours now. It's not just with any particular tag either.

Comment: I experience the same problem for my watched tags, e.g. keras or machine-learning. The "Newest" tab is active by default when I click on one of the watched tags however it does not show the newest questions. The more strange thing is that sometimes I need to click "Newest" **multiple times** so that the most recent questions appears. It's very annoying. This was not the case before (adding filtering feature).

Comment: Possibly related on über meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330833/332043

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://shouldiblamecaching.com/